# Error running Tomcat 7.0.34: Can't find catalina.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I have a Java web application that I have been working on 6 months ago and when I last worked on it, it would run perfectly. When I ran it again 6 months later I got this error "Can't find catalina.jar". I'm using IntelliJ 13.0 and tomcat 7.0.34. 
Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you start tomcat using the provided scripts without using IntelliJ?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

The method is to chose right Tomcat Home and Tomcat base directory in the wizard Run/Debug Configuration -> Server -> Configure...

Answer (score 2):

Catalina.jar should already be present in tomcat/lib directory.

Is your tomcat home set up correctly, and is the jar there.

Answer (score 1):

Also ensure that the user trying to access the lib directory and Catalina.jar etc.. has access to do so (Unix).

Answer (score 0):

This problem may have occurred because Tomcat was loaded into the Program Files directory. Intellij IDEA cannot read files from Tomcat/lib inside program files. It can be decide: to run the IDEA with administrator rights or download Tomcat to another directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have already fixed this problem,you need to correct the Tomcat Home's path.

My problem is that I renamed the file of *apache-tomcat-8.5.9* to *Tomcat*,then the *Idea* could not distinguish the version.